# Negative-Binomial vs Poisson for Count Data

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

Say that I was modelling the number of upvotes for a Facebook post under two treatments. What would be a more ideal distribution for modelling these counts: negative-binomial or a Poisson?

What would be the trade-offs here?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what the distribution looks like (or hypothetically would look like, at least)?  Empirically, the overdispersion parameter from NB would tell you which one was the better fit.

Comment: So NB works in more cases than Poisson?

Comment: Poisson is the more "general purpose" model. Recall that NB is used when there is overdispersion.  Therefore: the overdispersion parameter (alpha) from NB will tell you if Poisson or NB is better for your data.  The null hypothesis is that alpha = 0.  If we cannot reject the null, present Poisson results.  If alpha is significantly different from 0 (i.e. there is overdispersion), then present NB results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $Y \sim$ Poisson$(\lambda)$ we have $\text{E}(Y) = \lambda$ and $\text{Var}(Y) = \lambda$, so the variance should at least be well-approximated by the mean.  Often in real applications we find that the variance for count data is larger than the mean.

If on the other hand $Y \sim$ negative binomial$(r, p)$ we have $\text{E}(Y) = rp / (1 - p)$ which is less than $\text{Var}(Y) = rp / (1 - p)^2$, so the negative binomial is sometimes used to account for what's called "overdispersion."  The only real downside is that the model is slightly less parsimonious, but that arguably isn't much of a downside.

Comment: A downside (that I personally would not be that concerned with) is that the Negative Binomial does not have a theoretical justification for use in analysis of count data, while the Poisson distribution does. In fact, the best justification for use of the Negative Binomial is that the Poisson distribution sits on the open boundary of the family of Negative Binomials.

Comment: Whoa - crazy claim. Can I get a few references to back that up?

Comment: @zero: I think you are asking for a reference to the claim that the Poisson distribution sits on the open boundary of the family Negative Binomials? You can see it in [Related Distributions:Poisson section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). I say it sits on the open boundary, as a negative binomial approaches a Poisson as $p \rightarrow 0, p / r \rightarrow \lambda$, but is not defined at $p = 0, r = \infty$.

Comment: @CliffAB I disagree that the Negative Binomial does not have a theoretical justification. Consider the example in baseball of how many pitches it takes for a batter to move from the home base. This is count data, but can easily be thought of as a negative binomial where the probability of moving is $p$, you have $x-1$ failures before your success, and thats when you stop.

Comment: @Greenparker: yes, the NB does have a theoretical derivation, and in your case would be theoretically justified. But my point was that the data it is often used to model (i.e. hurricane counts in a season, gene expression counts) often do **not** follow naturally from the theoretical derivation, but rather just that empirically it fits what we actually see better than Poisson, even though the Poisson model logically seems like a better fit.

Comment: @CliffAB, I do think that there is a natural interpretation for settings such as gene expression: The negative binomial distribution arises if the rate parameters that govern the count data are drawn from a gamma distribution. For example, the rate at which a particular cell expresses a gene may be fixed (Poisson distribution for # of expressions for a *specific* cell) but the number of counts in the population would be NB-distributed if the individual rate parameters are drawn from a gamma distribution.

Comment: @TillHoffmann: so you are saying that if $\lambda \sim$ gamma($\alpha, \beta$) and $Y | \lambda \sim Pois(\lambda)$, then $Y \sim NB(\nu, \eta)$? Interesting, I was not actually aware of that. That is great justification for the Negative Binomial.

Comment: @CliffAB, yes, that's right. Here are some more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma.E2.80.93Poisson_mixture

Answer (score 2):

Aside from looking at the mean and variance of the response, you also need to understand if it makes sense for the data to come from a Poisson or a Negative Binomial distribution.

Your setup clearly suits Poisson regression in principle.

For [Negative-Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) distribution, you will need to have a data setup where you say "how many up-votes this post gets before the first down vote", and that will conform to a negative binomial. But as it stands, you cannot setup your problem in a way such that a NB distribution can make intuitive sense here.